# TypeError: oResults.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this error

```
 $.ajax({
           url:    '${searchPatientFileURL}',
           data:    data,
success: function(oResults)
            {

               console.log("Results:...->"+oResults);
               oResults.sort(function(a, b){
                  return a.lastname.toLowerCase() > b.lastname.toLowerCase() ? 
                  1 : a.lastname.toLowerCase() < b.lastname.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 0;
               });
});
```

I don't know why it is occurring.
Please can any one help me solve my issue?

Comment: oResults is not an array here

Comment: JavaScript isn't Java.

Comment: What are the contents of the URL you're making the request to?

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox (I use the firebug plugin with firefox) you can console.log the object and click on it in the console to inspect the properties of that object. Can you console.log(oResults); and update the answer on what oResults is and what properties it has?

Comment: Yes I wrote console.log(oResults); and the output is : "[{"firstname":"Vijay","lastname":"Gajera","gender":"Male","dateofbirth":"01/01/2013","id":372}]"

Answer (score 0):

For me the your URL dosen't look fine. 
Looks like you are using the JSP expression language for the url, which you cannot do from the client browser.

If this is the case you are using wrong URL so U can't get the correct response.